# Absolute value definition without logic

Tags: absolute-value

The absolute value of $x$ is defined as $x$ if $x>= 0$ and $-x$ otherwise.

But is it possible to define it without using logic? People say that $|x|=\sqrt{x^2},$ but that can give either $x$ or $-x.$
So maybe I can put the solutions to $\sqrt{x^2}$ in a tuple and refer to 2nd element, as $(-x, x)?$ So would this be correct?:
$|x|=(\sqrt{x^2})_2$

Comment: _"but that can give either x or -x"_ This is untrue. Look into [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569629/is-sqrtx-always-positive) and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448885/is-sqrt64-considered-8-or-is-it-8-8).

Comment: $\sqrt{}$ denotes the principal root

Comment: $\max(x, -x)$ (if we are talking about real numbers, of course). Of course, computing $\max$ might require some logic itself.

Comment: "*I wanted to see if it is possible to define it without using logic...*"  and a name like "*professional coder*".  For this it may be worth asking what sort of numbers specifically you are trying to work with.  If you are working with numbers on a computer, such as with signed integers... you can just directly modify the bit corresponding to the sign to be zero (*corresponding to a positive number*).

Comment: In a programming context, taking the effort to square a number followed by square rooting a number, you may encounter errors when the square of the number winds up requiring more memory to store than the data type it was assigned as, leading to inaccuracies.