# Fractional power

Tags: real-numbers

By the definition of square root, we can take square root of $16$ as $\pm4$.

But in problems, why do we take $16^{\frac12}$ as $4$?

And also how can we say, if $a^m=b^n$ then $a=b^{m/n}$?

Because when we take $x^2=a$, we solve it as $x=\pm{a^{1/2}}$.

Comment: This site uses [MathJax formatting of formulas](//math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). [More tips here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959). *(autocomment)*

Comment: Please correct the tag if I have done wrong?

Comment: we have $\sqrt{16}=4$ not $-4$

Comment: This question has been reiterated a lot of times here, see for instance [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492707/why-fx-sqrtx-is-a-function/).

Comment: I've fixed up your question a little bit, but it is still phrased in very low quality (there's only that much I can do).

Answer (score 0):

We take square root of 16 as 4 only when a negative solution is not viable e.g. when you are counting the number of objects, an answer of '-4' will not make any sense and is ignored.