# Is $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ equal to $\sqrt{x}$ or $\pm\sqrt{x}$?

Tags: graphing-functions, radicals

I have seen that when graphing $f\left(x\right)=x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ the graph only outputs positive and zero values (the range is greater or equal to 0), but according to what I know about algebra (correct me if I'm wrong), $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is equal to $\pm\sqrt{x}$.

Is it because $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ actually equals $\sqrt{x}$ or because $f\left(x\right)=x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ can only be a function if we ignore negative outputs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is a function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492707/why-fx-sqrtx-is-a-function)

Comment: Unless the context explicitly demands something else, most of the times it is assumed that $x\mapsto x^{1/2}$ is the function $g:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ such that $(g(x))^2=x$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the square root $$\sqrt x=x^{1/2},$$ which is defined to be the *non-negative solution* for $y$ of the equation $y^2=x$ for $x\geq0$, and the solutions of the equation $$x^2=y,$$ which are actually $x=\pm\sqrt y$.

If you view this as a complex function, then there would be two *branches* of the function; and you would have to decide if you take the one or the other.

Note that a function, however, only ever takes *one* $y$ value for each $x$ value, and never two. Then, this would not be a function anymore.