# why is $y^2=x$ not the same as $y=\sqrt{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Yes I know this is probably a monumentally stupid question.  Surely $\sqrt{4}$ is both 2 and -2, yet only 2 is shown as an answer.  But $y^2=4$ shows both answers as I'd say it should.  I probably knew this at one time!

Comment: The symbol $\sqrt{x}$ means the nonnegative square root of $x$.  See [Why is $\sqrt{x}$ a function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033604/why-is-sqrtx-a-function/1033616#1033616).

Comment: Ah!  So we simply define 'sqrt' as only giving positive answers.  Nuts, I must have known that once.  Thanks.

Comment: @RayAndrews: It's certainly true that the collection of square roots of $4$ are $\{2,-2\}$. However, it would not make much sense for the symbol $\sqrt{4}$ to represent both $2$ and $-2$ at the same time, as this would seem to imply that $2=-2$. This is part of the reason why the accepted mathematical convention is that $\sqrt{x}$ denotes the nonnegative square root of $x$. (I say "nonnegative" rather than "positive" because $\sqrt{0}=0$, and $0$ is neither positive nor negative.)

Comment: Major ambiguity for $\sqrt{z}$ when $z$ is complex or negative.

Comment: Recommend you get some graph paper, then draw, by hand, the graph of $x=y^2$  on one piece, the graph of $y=\sqrt x$ on another. Use a calculator so as to plot intermediate points in both, not just where both coordinates are integers.

Comment: @Joe: There's a semantic logic to that. 'y' is a variable so in: 'y^2=4' 'y' can be any number that satisfies.  But: '√4', having no variable within it, suggests a single answer.

Comment: @WillJagy: That's just what lead to this question: I wanted the whole parabola not just half of it.

Comment: Ray, understood. I do try to get people to match up algebra questions with graphing. One type of question that becomes very clear by graph, For what values of real constant $C$ does $x^3 - 12 x - C$  have three real roots?  Answer: draw $y=x^3 - 12 x$  and find the values of $C$ for which the horizontal line $y=C$   intersects the graph three times.

Answer (score 1):

As noticed in the comments, the equation $y^2=x$ with $x\ge 0$ has the following pair of solutions

- $y_1=\sqrt x\ge0$
- $y_2=-\sqrt x\le0$

with $y=0\iff x=0$, by the definition of $\sqrt x$.

Refer also to the related

- [Why $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is a function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/492707/505767)